# Error: cannot find module npm-shrinkwrap

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, npm, shrinkwrap

Setting up bootstrap with grunt.
Getting the following error:

Cannot find module npm-shrinkwrap

Tried npm install shrinkwrap, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

run `npm install` first on bower_components\bootstrap directory. Then, run `grunt dist`.